# Predicted values of each fold in K-Fold Cross Validation in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I have performed 10-fold cross validation on a dataset that I have using python sklearn,

```
result = cross_val_score(best_svr, X, y, cv=10, scoring='r2')
print(result.mean())
```

I have been able to get the mean value of the r2 score as the final result. I want to know if there is a way to print out the predicted values for each fold( in this case 10 sets of values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`cross_val_predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) function.

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I want to know if I can print out the results for each fold separately

Comment: I understand that it has the predictions for all the folds. I want to know if there is a way to print out the results of each fold separately. for example, 1st Fold : {....}, 2nd Fold : {......} .....etc.

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, just to add to @jh314, `cross_val_predict` does return all the predictions, but we do not know which fold each prediction belongs to. To do that, we need to provide the folds, instead of an integer:

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, StratifiedKFold 

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
X=iris.iloc[:,:4]
y=(iris['species'] == "versicolor").astype('int')

rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=111,shuffle=True)

pred = cross_val_predict(rfc, X, y, cv=skf)
```

And now we iterate through the Kfold object and pull out the predictions corresponding to each fold:

```
fold_pred = [pred[j] for i, j in skf.split(X,y)]
fold_pred

[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: Nice approach! May I know is it possible to extract the real indexes of the misclassified or classified instances in this scenario? I found no answer for this question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686327/how-do-i-get-misclassified-instances-and-their-indices-for-each-fold-cross-valid

Comment: Is it possible by using kfold.split(X, y, groups=None) ? or Any workaround something like sample_indices_ or else?

Comment: please have a look at this question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956643/not-getting-indices-of-misclassified-instances-during-kfold-cross-validation

Answer (score 0):

To print the predictions for each fold,

```
for k in range(2,10):
    result = cross_val_score(best_svr, X, y, cv=k, scoring='r2')
    print(k, result.mean())
    y_pred = cross_val_predict(best_svr, X, y, cv=k)
    print(y_pred)
```

Comment: This performs the same function as `print(result)`. I want to print them separately for each fold

Comment: @KrishiH `result` gives you the scores whereas `y_pred` gives the predictions. plz check.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. `y_pred` returns all the prediction. I want to print the prediction for each fold separately.

Comment: @KrishiH adding `cv` as a param to `cross_val_predict` gives the predictions. thanks!