# How to get indices of instances during cross-validation

Tags: python, classification, cross-validation, training-data, indices

I am doing a binary classification. May I know how to extract the real indexes of the misclassified or classified instances of the training data frame while doing K fold cross-validation? I found no answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686327/how-do-i-get-misclassified-instances-and-their-indices-for-each-fold-cross-valid#comment120107424_66686327).

I got the values in folds as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718734/predicted-values-of-each-fold-in-k-fold-cross-validation-in-sklearn/65369657#comment120107820_65369657):

```
skf=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=111,shuffle=False)
cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=skf, scoring='roc_auc')
fold_pred = [pred[j] for i, j in skf.split(X_train,y_train)]
fold_pred
```

Is there any method to get index of misclassified (or classified ones)? So the output is a dataframe that only has misclassified(or classified) instances while doing cross validation.

Desired output:
Missclassified instances in the dataframe with real indices.

```
     col1 col2 col3 col4  target
13    0    1    0    0    0
14    0    1    0    0    0
18    0    1    0    0    1
22    0    1    0    0    0
```

where input has 100 instances, 4 are misclassified (index number 13,14,18 and 22) while doing CV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `cross_val_predict` you already have the predictions. It's a matter of subsetting your data frame where the predictions are not the same as your true label, for example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, StratifiedKFold 
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import pandas as pd

data = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data[:,:5],columns=data.feature_names[:5])
df['label'] = data.target

rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=111,shuffle=True)

pred = cross_val_predict(rfc, df.iloc[:,:5], df['label'], cv=skf)

df[df['label']!=pred]
 
     mean radius  mean texture  ...  mean smoothness  label
3          11.42         20.38  ...          0.14250      0
5          12.45         15.70  ...          0.12780      0
9          12.46         24.04  ...          0.11860      0
22         15.34         14.26  ...          0.10730      0
31         11.84         18.70  ...          0.11090      0
```

Comment: Hi, as far I understand, pred would give the predictions for all the inputs of the dataset here.   Could you please tell me, how do I match which prediction was for which input value (through indices). To elaborate, how do I create a new column for the existing dataFrame where I have the predicted values in addition to the corresponding original labels